# In python how to check inequality to "float("inf")"?

Tags: python

I have following simple code. Just confused why the second evaluation is True. Could anyone explain to me? So what is exactly the difference between "is" and "=="?

```
a = float("inf")
print a != float("inf")
print a is not float("inf") # why is this True?

b = 1
print b != 1
print b is not 1

c = int(1)
print c != int(1)
print c != int(1)
```

Output:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux

False
True
False
False
False
False
```

Comment: @Prajwal: You're thinking of some other language's use of the keyword. `is` is an object identity test in Python.

Comment: One more question. Then wouldn't it be preferred using "==" if just for checking arithmetic equality? I feel using "is" sounds more pythonic though.

Comment: Don't write code based on what it sounds like. That'd be stupid. Write code based on what it actually means. You want `==`.